# Копирование большого количества файлов с диска на удаленную машину в Linux

Tags: linux, файлы, файловая-система, резервное-копирование, передача-данных

суть вопроса такова:

Имеется диск на хосте А, размером 3.7 Тб, на который записано 1.3 Тб данных на разделе NTFS.

Имеется удаленный хост В, на котором есть 2 Тб свободного места на разделе ext4

Задача: скопировать с хоста А на хост В 1.3 Тб данных.

Почему я не использую rsync? Потому что при копировании мелких файлов скорость передачи падает до 100 кбайт/с, а таковых там достаточно много

Почему не dd? Потому что копируется весь раздел, размером 3.7 Тб.

Подскажите, как правильно и относительно быстро скопировать данные на удаленный хост? Возможно, можно использовать dd, но не создавать образ размера 3.7 тб?

ОС на хосте А: Ubuntu 18.04

На хосте В: Debian 8

Comment: `tar`+`ssh` сойдёт?

Comment: @Fat-Zer мне не важно, что использовать, главное чтобы было быстро и не копировало все 3.7 Тб раздела :D

Comment: да, если тормозит ФС из-за очень больших каталогов, то адекватного способа сделать быстро скорей всего не будет...

Comment: А надо прям раздел или хватит просто файлов\папок?

Comment: @donRumata, в моем случае нужно было просто скопировать файлы и папки

Comment: Можно тогда ещё попробовать "Syncthing".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Обычно самый простой способ — это запаковать файлы в архив и отправить на удалённый хост. Можно это сделать обычным [`tar`](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=tar&category=1)'ом

```
tar cf /path/to/my/tarfile.tar.gz -C /путь/к/источнику .
scp /path/to/my/tarfile.tar.gz host_В:/tmp/
ssh host_В tar xf /tmp/tarfile.tar.gz -C /путь/к/назначению
```

Но т.к. на удалённом хосте, по условию задачи, не хватит места и для архива и для данных, то можно воспользоваться тем, что утилита `tar` умеет читать и писать в/из стандартного ввода/вывода и сделать всё в одно действие:

```
tar cz -C /путь/к/источнику . | ssh host_В tar xz -C /путь/к/назначению
```

Если в ssh включена компрессия или канал достаточно широкий, то следует убрать ключ `z` из аргументов `tar`.

Из минусов — отсутствие возможности возобновить передачу при сбое.

Comment: Это решает проблему проседания скорости при копировании большого количества маленьких файлов?

Comment: @WGOS, смотря чем вызвана проблема — если тем что scp/rsync каждый файл передают отдельно — то да; Если тормозами самой ФС из-за очень больших каталогов, то скорей всего нет...

Comment: @WGOS не уверен, как `tar` обрабатывает ошибки чтения... есть `--ignore-failed-read`; можно оный атрибут попробовать добавить, если просто умирает на ошибке чтения...

Comment: ну, оно копирует файлы на достаточно большой скорости -- уже хорошо. Добавил аргумент. Оставляю на ночь -- утром посмотрю, что будет.

P.S. Почему-то не могу использовать 'at' для указания твоего имени, странно

Comment: Скорость передачи пока держится на уровне 80 мбайт/с

Comment: @WGOS, если в комментариях только два собеседника, то имя автора ответа/вопроса указать нельзя... хз зачем это сделали...

Comment: Не знал - редко пользуюсь StackOverflow

Comment: Автор всегда получает уведомление о новых комментариях под его постом, а другие только если их упомянули. По этому и нет смысла обращаться к автору через @, если никого больше нет.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf, это сильно раздражает неоднородностью...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, все скопировалось, потерянных данных вроде как нет. Спасибо)