# Как прочитать локальный файл в удаленный файл?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Хостовая машина хранит много конфигурационных файлов, содержимое которых должно быть на удаленной машине, я пытаюсь прочитать содержимое локального файла в файл на удаленной машине:

```
cat files/main.conf > file.txt
```

При этом `files/main.conf` хранится на хосте, а файл `file.txt` хранится на удаленном сервере. Пытаюсь реализовать это так:

```
sshpass -p password ssh root@ip_server bash -s < script.sh
```

А `script.sh` пытается сделать запись в удаленный файл с локального хоста

```
#!/bin/bash
cat files/main.conf > file.txt
cat files/none.conf > abc.txt
cat files/foo.conf > bar.txt
# и т.д
```

Возникает ошибка:

> No such file or directory

Что естественно, потому что `root` пользователь пытается найти директиву `files` и прочитать из нее файл на удаленной машине.

Но как бы сделать чтобы чтение было с хоста, а запись на сервер в файл?

Comment: Залейте файлы по sftp

Comment: @Mike, скорее всего это то что мне нужно, спасибо

Comment: а ещё заодно посмотри, что такое `scp` ну и, может быть, `rsync` для продвинутого случая... ну и мой любимый трюк с `tar`'ом и трубами: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/927219/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83-%d0%b2-linux/927220#927220

Comment: Както ковырял одну железяку на линуксе - качал файл через эмулятор zmodem (или больше получилось похоже на xmodem) написанный на ash через телнет... Закинул туда статически собранный неткат каким-то чудом и вот выкачивал неткатом оттуда... Ну а тут ссх есть в комплекте с сцп из коробки)

Answer (score 3):

Воспользуйтесь SCP [man scp](https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp). Так как имена файлов локально и на удалённой машине отличаются, то создайте словарь имён файлов и копируйте их в цикле. Скрипт будет выглядеть так:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A filemap=([main]=file [none]=abc [foo]=bar)
dest="user@remotehost:~/files"
for source in "${!filemap[@]}"; do target="${filemap[$source]}"
    scp files/$source.conf $dest/$target.txt
done
```

Попробовать:

```
$ mkdir files
$ touch files/{main,none,foo}.conf

$ ./script.sh
none.conf         100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00
foo.conf          100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00
main.conf         100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00 

$ ssh user@remotehost 'ls -1 ~/files/'
abc.txt
bar.txt
file.txt
```

---

PS SSH подключение [без пароля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/338540/217579), т.е. по публичному ключу, должно быть настроено.